# Gradio - Way to show active hyperlink on chatbot output

Tags: python, gradio

How to show an active hyperlink in the output of a gradio chatbot?
I checked this but don't fully understand if the issue has been resolved or not, and where's the solution:
https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/issues/837

This is the closest I've gotten to it, but the link shows as text and is not active:

```
def my_function(text):
    href = "https://www.google.com/"
    return f"This is a link to Google: {href}"

gr.Interface(my_function, inputs="text", outputs="text").launch()
```

Comment: hi there, have you found a solution?

Comment: Not a good one. Nobody answered, which is surprising to me. I am working on a hack using jQuery under the bot instead. Not happy with the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use markdown:

```
def my_function(text):
href = "https://www.google.com/"
return f"[This is a link to Google]({href})"
```